# CKeditor 5 Cannot upload image in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, ckeditor5

I'm using ckeditor to upload images in laravel
It works fine and uploads image to the folder but at front it gives an alert error of "cannot upload image:imagename" and removes the image from editor

Imageuploadcontroller:

```
public function storeImage(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->hasFile('upload')) {
            $originName = $request->file('upload')->getClientOriginalName();
            $fileName = pathinfo($originName, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            $extension = $request->file('upload')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $fileName = $fileName . '_' . time() . '.' . $extension;
    
            $request->file('upload')->move(public_path('media'), $fileName);
    
            $url = asset('media/' . $fileName);
            
            return response()->json(['fileName' => $fileName, 'uploaded'=> true, 'url' => $url]);
        }
    }
```

Script:

```
 <script>
                        ClassicEditor
                                .create( document.querySelector( '#longdescription' ), {
                                    ckfinder: {
                    uploadUrl: "{{route('image.upload').'?_token='.csrf_token()}}",
        }


                                })
                                .then( editor => {
                                        console.log( editor );
                                } )
                                .catch( error => {
                                        console.error( error );
                                } );
                </script>
```

Comment: please check https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/deep-dive/upload-adapter.html#how-does-the-image-upload-work

Answer (score 0):

You may use to look at your developer tools and go to the network to see if the request is sent properly. I had the same error like this
[shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Lb15.png).

In my case the error was a missing `=` in the upload URL in the following code:

```
ckfinder: {
 uploadUrl: `{{ route('upload.image').'?_token'.csrf_token() }}`
}
```

So when I added the `=` after the `_token` key, the modified code looks like this:

```
ckfinder: {
 uploadUrl: `{{ route('upload.image').'?_token='.csrf_token() }}`
}
```